# "It will spend you an hour" vs "It will take you an hour"

Tags: verbs, sentence-structure

"It will spend you an hour," is incorrect grammatically, I know this. "It will take you an hour," is the correct form, *but I don't know why.*

Similarly, both "you will spend an hour," and "you will take an hour," are correct. Also similarly, I don't have the means to explain why. I just know it is. Help me.

Answer (score 1):

*You will spend an hour* and *you will take an hour* have different meanings.

If you spend an hour doing something, you fill up the time with that activity, whether or not you have finished a particular task by the end of the hour.

If you take an hour to do something, you finish the task and you require an hour to do so.

Answer (score 0):

> "It will spend you an hour," is incorrect grammatically, I know this. "It will take you an hour," is the correct form, but I don't know why.

*Spend* usually works like this:

- *X spends Y on Z* - X generally is a person, Y is some form of currency/money, and Z is something X wants and gets at the end of the transaction.
- To identify what you're trying to get when you spend something, *on X* is needed.

*It will spend you an hour* doesn't work because *it* is not a personal pronoun and *you* is not a form of currency, and you don't have an *on* in there.

Time (*hour* is a form of time) can be figuratively considered a form of currency (you spend time doing things to "buy" or "trade for" a result), and time can also more directly be considered something you consume or use to accomplish a result.

So both *spend* and *take* can be used with *hour*.